# RecycleView adapter not adding to the view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to implement a RecycleView adapter that has CardViews as each row.  The card views do not show up even though I have the adapter created and attached to the view of the activity.

I am using the Tabbed activity and trying to modify the OnCreateView() method.

[image: img]

As seen in this picture I get nothing in the recycle view but I am expecting "Test Title" and "Test Message" in a CardView.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_TAB_NUMBER = "tab_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int tabNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_TAB_NUMBER, tabNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coversations, container, false);
        RecyclerView recycle = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        List<RecyclerData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        RecycleViewAdapter adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(list);
        recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerData r = new RecyclerData("Test Title", "Test Message", 0);
        list.add(r);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show `RecycleViewAdapter` class code

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a layout manager to your recycler view. In your case try adding a LinearLayoutManager to your recycler view.

```
// use a linear layout manager
recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
```

Comment: Done. Check now